# Keys' exchange between server and client

Tags: ssl

When SSL is used, as far as I have understood, the server sends to the client a public key to encrypt the sent data with, and that makes it safe to send data FROM THE CLIENT TO THE SERVER. For the other way around, to send data from server to client in a safe manner, too, what is the procedure that takes place? Does the client (e.g. a normal home pc) generate its own pair of keys and sends its own public key to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To secure the transmission you follow a specific protocol called handshake. For TLS (which is the updated version of SSL) it goes like this:

- Client communicates its intention to do encryption to the server (this is a **clear text** message)
- The server replies with by sending its certificate, the protocol he agrees on and a random number (**clear text**).
- The client generates a pre-shared-key (PSK) and **encrypts** it with the server's certificate
- The client and server generate with the PSK and the random number a **master secret key**
- Client and server can now communicate with the **master key** that no one knows.

More details [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake)